# Is there a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n a^{1/i}$?

Tags: summation, summation-method, z-transform

Just what the question says. $\sum_{i=1}^n a^{i}$ has quite well known equation (geometric series). I couldn't find any resources for power $ {1/n} $ though.

On a slight tangent; I tried solving it using Unilateral Z transform (Z transform has served me well in the past for solving summations, by solving the difference equation $ S_n = S_{n-1} + a^{1/n} $ where $ S_0=0 $). Here too, however, $ Z\{a^{1/n}\}$ is not a standard form and I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Not an exact one, but hopefully it admits an integral approximation for large $n$. It's also asymptotic to $a$ for large $n$.

Comment: When $n$ is large sum will contain many numbers near to 1, that's why it will be asymptotic equal to $n$ at large $n$.